# Um dos campos devem ser obrigatório - DataAnnotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, dataannotations

Exemplo de código:

**Model:**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo CPF ou CNPJ obrigatório")]
[Display(Name = "CPF")]
public string CPF { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "CNPJ")]
public string CNPJ { get; set; }
```

Usuário deve preencher um dos campos CPF ou CNPJ (ou ele preenche CPF, ou ele preenche CNPJ). Como posso fazer isso com `DataAnnotation`?

Comment: Por curiosidade: já que vai usar como `string` por que não usa o mesmo campo?

Comment: @jbueno, pode me dar um exemplo ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda ééér, usar só um campo pra duas coisas(?)

Comment: @jbueno, isso mesmo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é com decoração por atributos que você vai resolver. Implemente [`IValidatableObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject(v=vs.110).aspx) no *Model*:

```
public class MeuModel : IValidatableObject
{
    ...

    [Display(Name = "CPF")]
    public string CPF { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "CNPJ")]
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(CPF) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(CNPJ)) 
        {    
            yield return new ValidationResult("É necessário definir ou CPF ou CNPJ.", new [] { "CPF", "CNPJ" });
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CPF) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(CNPJ)) 
        {    
            yield return new ValidationResult("CPF e CNPJ não podem ambos ter valor.", new [] { "CPF", "CNPJ" });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interessante, não sabia dessa.

Comment: Você digita um vazio e o outro correto e ele não valida, é isso? Já tentou debugar o `Validate`?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Foi mal. Está arrumado. Obrigado!

Comment: Coloque um *breakpoint* no primeiro `if` e veja o que acontece. O jQuery Validate está correto até então.

Comment: Legal. Dá pra usar os dois juntos. Só precisa melhorar a configuração.